# What does 皮膚の裏側 mean?

Tags: meaning

> 白羽さんは鼻で笑い、笑った拍子に鼻がプーという音を出し、鼻水が鼻の穴に膜を作っているのが見えた。
>   　白羽さんの紙で作ったような乾燥しきった**皮膚の裏側**にも、膜をはるような水分があるのだなと、私がその膜が割れるのに気をとられていると、
>   「特にないですよ。僕は大体わかってるんで」 　と白羽さんが小声の早口で言った。

'rear of the skin'?

Comment: Why do people here downvote my questions even though I can't  find an answer at all to them but upvote massively simple questions with an answer that I can easily find with a search on internet? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means the skin of the nostrils. They are wet.

I think the writer described the other side of the surface skin of the nose as 皮膚の裏側.